# Release Build UWP C# Struct One Byte Larger than Debug

Tags: c#, marshalling, structlayout

I have a class hierarchy consisting of an abstract base class with a few helper methods and no fields, and a handful of derived classes with a variety of fields.  Here is MCRE code describing the classes in question:

```cs
namespace MarshalSizes {
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
    public abstract class BaseClass {
        public abstract int MySize { get; }
        public int BaseSize { get {
                return Marshal.SizeOf(GetType());
            } 
        }
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
    public class DerivedClass : BaseClass {
        public UInt32 a32bits;
        public UInt16 a16bits;
        public Byte onebyte;
        public Byte twobyte;
        public override int MySize {
            get {
                return Marshal.SizeOf(GetType());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is in a UWP app.  I have simple code that generates a popup box thusly:

```cs
    DerivedClass classThing = new DerivedClass();
    Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog dialog = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(
        String.Format("DerivedClass.BaseSize = {0}\nDerivedClass.MySize = {1}",
           classThing.BaseSize, classThing.MySize));

    await dialog.ShowAsync();
```

Simple enough.  When I run a debug build:
[image: Dialog from debug build]
When I run a release build:
[image: Dialog from release build]

This is wreaking havoc in my real project, where everything is carefully designed to be sized in multiples of 32 bytes (has to do with a communication protocol with a device).

What's going on here?  Why does the size grow by a byte in a release build?

EDIT: Since it's been asked, here's a somewhat simplified example of how this type gets marshaled, in a method in the ABC:

```cs
// Given Byte[] outbuffer of appropriate size
int size = Marshal.SizeOf(GetType());
IntPtr iptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
Marshal.StructureToPtr(this, iptr, false);
Marshal.Copy(iptr, outbuffer, 0, size);
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(iptr);
```

The `outbuffer` is part of a packet envelope class that includes CRC values generated over the byte array.

The above is for transmission; for reception, code like this is used:

```cs
// Given Byte[] buffer of enough inbound bytes
GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(buffer, GCHandleType.Pinned);
var packetType = Marshal.PtrToStructure<MyPacketClass>(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject());
handle.Free();
```

I'm open to suggestions of "better" ways of doing this, but I would still very much like to have the original question here answered.

Comment: Usually, if you're dealing with types that require specific layout and "punning", you'd use a `struct`, so that you can just do in place punning in both directions (Unsafe.As, MemoryMarshal.Cast, etc;); can you show how you're actually using this type in a scenario where the internal layout matters?

Comment: The type is used in binary communication with a device; ergo the internal layout is critical.  I am trying to avoid dependence on native code (other show-stopping problems there), while still taking advantage of inheritance (`struct`s can only implement `interface`s; they cannot inherit methods from an abstract base object) and polymorphism (which an interface would do for the struct, but without the benefit of code sharing).

Comment: *yeees*, but: that doesn't change anything - native isn't related, and the main *efficient* way of dealing with punning (treating raw bytes as typed data, and vice versa): is mainly struct oriented. Although if we're talking external data (as in this case), the "endianness" problem would also concern me, unless you're 100% certain this will always run on CPUs that match the required device endianness. You can always define a polymorphic class that has a single field of the struct that matches the required device layout. But: can you actually show your marshal usage here?

Comment: Again, emphasis: if this was me I'd use a struct for the punning - maybe using explicit field layout, and I'd use `Unsafe.SizeOf<T>()` to verify the size (because we won't be using `Marshal`) - then `Unsafe.As<...>` and `MemoryMarshal.Cast<...>` to do in-place punning - usually punning the bytes to the type, which allows you to read from, or write to, the bytes data as a single instance of that struct. I suspect you'll find this simply side steps the problem you're seeing. And if I want polymorphism: stick a field of the the struct in the class

Comment: Valid points all, and I may end up refactoring this into value types and use some sort of helper class for the common actions (namely, marshaling the content in and out of byte arrays to be sent down the communication channel).  As far as Endianness, in this case it's an internal-use-only application where I can accurately predict the platforms involved.  All of that said, I'd still quite like to understand why the size changes between Release and Debug, especially since things usually get smaller in Release builds, not bigger.

Comment: You might get a better response if you ask on https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues

Comment: @BrianA.Henning "I'd still quite like to understand why the size changes between Release and Debug" - it is a good question, however: I can't make it repro, although to be clear: I'm not in a UWP context; maybe it is something specific to that, but... I admit I am intrigued, and I'd like to know the answer!